# Open only one modal from different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, href

I am trying to get a report from my created tables. The thing is I have 3 different button to trigger 3 different modal right now. This approach works but I think it is unnecessary to create them seperately. I want only one modal with auto routed to related "Action". I think it will be solved with jquery but I can't seem to understand.

The buttons that triggers modals is below.

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GeneralModal" class="dropdown-item" href="#">General Report </a>             
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VehicleModal" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vehicle Report</a>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#WarrantylModal" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Warranty Report</a>
                    </div>
```

My modals are below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="GeneralModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<form action="/Export/ExportGeneral" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Excel Report</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group m-form__group row m--margin-top-20">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        Start Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date1" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose start date">
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        End Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" name="date2" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose end date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Report </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="WarrantyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<form action="/Export/ExportWarranty" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Excel Report</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group m-form__group row m--margin-top-20">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        Start Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date1" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose start date">
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        End Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" name="date2" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose end date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Report </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="VehicleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<form action="/Export/ExportVehicle" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Excel Report</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group m-form__group row m--margin-top-20">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        Start Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date1" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose start date">
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        End Date
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" name="date2" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Choose end date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Report </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The only changing part is the modal's,

```
<form action="/Export/ExportGeneral" role="form" method="post">
```

Depending on the triggered modal it route to another action such as,

ExportGeneral
ExportWarranty
ExportVehicle

What I am asking is if there is a thing that help me to click the different buttons but open them in only one modal which's

```
<form action="/Export/ExportGeneral" role="form" method="post">
```

Change's automatically depending on, clicked button. (Maybe an id to buttons ?)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your anchor tag, you just need to replace your code with mine:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GeneralModal" id="general-export-button" data-url="/Export/ExportGeneral" class="dropdown-item" href="#">General Report </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GeneralModal" id="warranty-export-button" data-url="/Export/ExportWarranty" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vehicle Report</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GeneralModal" id="vehicle-export-button" data-url="/Export/ExportVehicle" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Warranty Report</a>
```

Now on the bottom of your page, add this jQuery code and everything will work fine.

```
<script>
$("#general-export-button, #warranty-export-button, #vehicle-export-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $("#multpurpose-form");
    form.prop("action", $(this).data("url"));
});
```

Now I will explain what is happening in my code. All anchor tags are linked to a single modal. The action method of form in the linked modal is changing against "anchor tag data-url" through jQuery code.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. It works perfectly Have a good day, sir

Answer (score 0):

change your html like

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a onclick="openModal('GeneralModal')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">General Report </a>             
       <a onclick="openModal('VehicleModal')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vehicle Report</a>
       <a onclick="openModal('WarrantylModal')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Warranty Report</a>
</div>
```

and give your form id so we can change thier attribute using javascript like

```
<form action="" id="modalForm" role="form" method="post">
```

then in script

```
function openModal(modalName){
    if(modalName == 'GeneralModal'){
        $("#modalForm").attr("action",'/Export/ExportGeneral');
        $("#modalId").modal('show');
    }
    else if(modalName == 'VehicleModal'){
        $("#modalForm").attr("action",'/Export/ExportVehicle');
        $("#modalId").modal('show');
    }
    else if(modalName == 'WarrantylModal'){
        $("#modalForm").attr("action",'/Export/ExportWarranty');
        $("#modalId").modal('show');
    }
}
```

i think it might solved your problem and optimized your code. :)